# in dexie.js, how do i define and query field of type set?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

here is my typescript definion:

```js
interface MyBlogPost{
  tx:string
  labels: Set<number>
}
```

Basicly a blog post with text and mutiple lables of type number. I have many of those that i need to store in indexeddb

I need to  query by a set of labels:

```js
function get_all_posts_by_labels(labels_subset:Set<number>){}
```

the function will return an array(or iterator) of the posts that have at least one label of `labels_subset`

in Dexie (or any other indexeddb wrapper), how do i create the database query method?

Comment: I recommend you convert from a Set to an Array and back upon writing/reading to/from the database. Arrays are indexable in [Dexie](https://dexie.org/docs/Indexable-Type).

Comment: Avoid using sets with indexedDB, just use arrays